# EDIT: add an identifier to a dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript, php, database

I'm pulling down two tables from the db. There's a Javascript function that adds a row from `Table2` into the `Table1`. What i've been trying to do is get the data from `Table1` on the `confirm_trade.php` page so I can put it into the db but can't figure out how to pull that row(`item_id`). I thought putting the table in a form would allow me to access them through the `$_POST` but that's not working. How to add an identifier to the jquery row so I can grab on the `confirm` page?

The appended rows coming from the jQuery function are the rows I need the item_id from.

```
function addto(obj)
{

var $row = $(obj).parents("tr");
var $table = $("#tradee");
var item_id = $row.find(".item-id").text();
var item_name = $row.find(".item-name").text();
var item_desc = $row.find(".item-desc").text();

var newTR = $("<tr><td>"+item_id+"</td><td>"+item_name+
"</td><td>"+item_desc+"</td></tr>");
$table.append(newTR);

 }
```

Table2:

```
   <div id='fixedDiv'> 
   <form action="confirm.php" method="post">        
   <table align="center" id="Table2">

    <tr><td>Other Item</td></tr>


    <?php while($rowi =$item->fetch_assoc())
    {?>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $rowi['item_id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $rowi['item_name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $rowi['item_description'];?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
    </div>

    <br>
```

Table 1:

```
        <table align="center" id="Table1">
        <tr><th>item_id</th>
            <th>Cat_id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    <?php while($row =$item_results->fetch_assoc())
    {?>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="item-id"> <?php echo $row['item_id']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $cat_id = $row['cat_id']; ?> </td>

        <td class="item-name"><?php echo $item_id = $row['item_name'];?></td>

        <td class="item-desc"><?php echo $item_descrip = $row['item_description'];?>
        </td>

        <td><input type="button" class="added" onclick="addto(this)" 
            value="Add" />
        <td><input type="button" class="removed" onclick="remove()" 
        value="Remove" >
        </td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: **Don't give a submit button a name of "submit"**, it will mask the form's submit method (i.e. `form.submit()` will try to call the button, not the method). A submit button rarely needs a name (it might need one if you have two buttons and want to know which was used). In that case, use a name that isn't the same as a standard form property (e.g. `orderSubmit` or `querySubmit` or similar).

Comment: this is not production code. just trying to figure out how to do this

Comment: Ok, but prototype code often finds its way into production.

Comment: @RobG I agree. I learned that the hard way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your code, you can use `<input type="hidden" name="some_hidden_data" value="field-value">`. be sure that you also wrap your table with `<form method="post"></form>`

the `hidden` field will be then included as $_POST['hidden_field_name'];

Comment: that has to come form the jquery function. the appended rows are the rows I need item_id from.

Comment: load data using JSON and $.ajax(); then echo the value as a hidden input element.

Comment: How to change this `var newTR = $("<tr><td>"+item_id+"</td><td>"+item_name+"</td><td>"+item_desc+"</td></tr>");` so I can get the hidden field in there?

Comment: `var newTR = $("<tr><td>"+item_id+"</td><td>"+item_name+"</td><td><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"\""+value+"></td></tr>");`